# Can't do equivalent of php DES decryption in Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, des

I can't create equivalent of php DES decryption in Java, always different result.
Here php-code what i want replicate:

```
$key = substr(sha1("m",true),0,8); //8-byte key
$iv = mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_DES,$key,hex2bin("0000000000000000"),MCRYPT_MODE_ECB); //get Iv
print(bin2hex($iv)."\n"); // "b5872289d3c49605"
$plain_text = "MZ4aXMCMO/TQAsZ2bYwagw==";
$plain_text = base64_decode($plain_text);
$cipher_text = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_DES, $key, $plain_text, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
print("\nThe ciphertext: ".$cipher_text);
print("\nThe expected  : "."489B4F2ADD728755");
```

and my Java code:

```
public static void desCipherDecrypt(String key, String encodedString) throws Exception {
    byte [] keyByte = Arrays.copyOf(DigestUtils.sha1(key),8);
    byte [] encodedByte = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedString);
    byte [] iv = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("B5872289D3C49605"); //same as Iv in php

    AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    Cipher desCipherDecrypt;

    desCipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CFB/NoPadding");
    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(keyByte);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    desCipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey,paramSpec);
    byte[] cryptByte = desCipherDecrypt.doFinal(encodedByte);

    System.out.println("resultBytes: "+Arrays.toString(cryptByte)+"\n");
    System.out.println("resultHex: "+DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cryptByte)+"\n");
    System.out.println("Decryption ended");
  }
...
desCipherDecrypt("m", "MZ4aXMCMO/TQAsZ2bYwagw==");
```

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated was removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: why php is `ECB` and in java `CFB`?

Comment: The ECB is some bizarre code to create an IV for CFB mode.

Comment: @zaph still I cannot see how generated key for `CFB` decryption can be same.

Comment: In fact, everything is more complicated. There is old applications written in delphi, and it invoke some method Cipher:= TDCP_Des.Create(nil);  Cipher.InitStr(AnsiKey, TDCP_sha1), and this php layer represent logic of this methods, like $key = substr(sha1("m",true),0,8); and generating Iv, but in general this is not important for question.

Answer (score 0):

So, it was a stupid mistake, for some reason I thought $cipher_text was encoded in Hex, but it was wrong, it's plain text, another reason was that mcrypt_decrypt for some reason doesn't uses standard block in a 64-bit, but 8-bit block.

after all answer will be,
    first, uses CFB8:

```
desCipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CFB8/NoPadding");
```

second read result byte like plain text

```
yte[] cryptByte = desCipherDecrypt.doFinal(encodedByte);
    for (int i = 0; i < cryptByte.length; i++ ){
                sResult += (char)(cryptByte[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, that CFB8 is the tricky part. That's not a good way to decode, you can just use `new String(cryptByte, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`

Comment: DES has a 8-byte block size, that is the **only** size. `CFB8` is an **encryption mode** that get's around block size padding. See [CFB8 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_(CFB)) *This way of proceeding is known as CFB-8 or CFB-1 (according to the size of the shifting)*.

Comment: Consider fixing the answer.